# Extract particular values from Excel file, place it into static text and generate .txt files

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am trying to read cells from .xls file and place them into particular spots in a static text and then have that generated as .txt file.

I managed to write code that generates what I need, but it only works for the first row in the .xls file. It generates 4 files according to the number of rows, but every file has values from the first row. I understand that I have static cell values for the first row in the code, but I am not sure how to amend this and get the code to go row by row/cell by cell and generate relevant .txt file for each row. My guess is that it needs to be incorporated into the for loop somehow?

For context, each row represents one printer, and these files are then used to import the printers into a system.

I'll be glad for any help/suggestions.

This is what my test .xls file looks like

```
prnt    server    desc      shortnam    driver      type
-----------------------------------------------------------
deupr   fransf    pr deu    ds22        adasd2      bizhub
frapr   fransf    pr fra    ds23        asdasda3    hp
grcpr   fransf    pr grc    ds24        asdasdq5    testhub
sinpr   fransf    pr sin    ds25        qdsad8      testhp
```

This is the state of my code (excuse the mess - I am a complete beginner):

```
import xlrd


xlsfilename='Testing.xls'
test = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfilename)
number_subjetcs=4 #will update this to require user input based on number of rows, test file has 4
number_columns=6 #is static

for row in range(number_subjetcs): 
    txtfilename = 'testfile' + str(row) + '.txt'
    with open(txtfilename, "w") as f:
        for row in range(1):            
            PrinterName = test.sheets()[0].cell(1,0).value
            ShortName = test.sheets()[0].cell(1,3).value
            Driver = test.sheets()[0].cell(1,4).value
            Model = test.sheets()[0].cell(1,5).value
            Desc = test.sheets()[0].cell(1,2).value
            Server = test.sheets()[0].cell(1,1).value
            f.write('VERSION = "0.1"')
            f.write('\n' + 'TIME = "20201015111814"')
            f.write('\n' + 'SYSTEM = "PR0"')
            f.write('\n' + 'RELEASE = "750"')
            f.write('\n' + '* DEVICE = {')
            f.write('\n' + '  NAME = "' + PrinterName + '"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PADEST = "' + ShortName + '"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PATYPE = "'+ Driver + '"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAMODEL = "'+ Model + '"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PACLASS = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAARCHIVER = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PALANGU = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PADISABLED = ""') #second file needs to have X here
            f.write('\n' + '  PANOQUERY = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PADUPCOPY = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PADUPLEX = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PASTORELOC = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PADFLTUTTL = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PADFLTSTTL = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PASYNC = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAMONI = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PASTANDORT = "' + Desc + '"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAMSG = "' + Desc + '"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAMSSERVER = "SERVER_0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAMETHOD = "C"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAPROSNAME = "\\\\' + Server + "\\" + PrinterName + '"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PALOMS = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PALPRCMD = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PALPDHOST = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PALPDPORT = "0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PACONNTIME = "0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAREADTIME = "0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PATRAYS = "0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAXSHIFT = "0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAYSHIFT = "0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAXSHUNIT = "MM"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAYSHUNIT = "MM"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PACRYPTMOD = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PACRYPTMET = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PANOVSERVR = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAPOOLART = "P"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PATRACE2 = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PATRACEF = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAPROTDATA = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAPROTCMD = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAPROTRES = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PAKEEPFILE = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  CHGNAME1 = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  CHGSAPREL1 = "750"')
            f.write('\n' + '  CHGSAPSYS1 = "PR0"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PADEVGRP = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  COLORPRT = "X"')
            f.write('\n' + '  PRINTMODE = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  INPUTTRAY = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '  PANOCHOICE = ""')
            f.write('\n' + '}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine on my computer after creating an Excel file with your sample data. Here's what I changed to make it work: The second for loop wasn't necessary so I removed it and outdented the code that was formerly in that loop. I changed the `range()` invocation to start at one and go one past the number of rows since the row numbers start at zero in xlrd. And I changed the `.cell` method calls to use the `row` variable instead of always getting values from row one.

```py
import xlrd


xlsfilename='Testing.xls'
test = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfilename)
number_subjetcs=4 #will update this to require user input based on number of rows, test file has 4
number_columns=6 #is static

for row in range(1, number_subjetcs + 1): 
    txtfilename = 'testfile' + str(row - 1) + '.txt'
    with open(txtfilename, "w") as f:
        PrinterName = test.sheets()[0].cell(row, 0).value
        ShortName = test.sheets()[0].cell(row, 3).value
        Driver = test.sheets()[0].cell(row, 4).value
        Model = test.sheets()[0].cell(row, 5).value
        Desc = test.sheets()[0].cell(row, 2).value
        Server = test.sheets()[0].cell(row, 1).value
        f.write('VERSION = "0.1"')
        f.write('\n' + 'TIME = "20201015111814"')
        f.write('\n' + 'SYSTEM = "PR0"')
        f.write('\n' + 'RELEASE = "750"')
        f.write('\n' + '* DEVICE = {')
        f.write('\n' + '  NAME = "' + PrinterName + '"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PADEST = "' + ShortName + '"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PATYPE = "'+ Driver + '"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAMODEL = "'+ Model + '"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PACLASS = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAARCHIVER = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PALANGU = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PADISABLED = ""') #second file needs to have X here
        f.write('\n' + '  PANOQUERY = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PADUPCOPY = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PADUPLEX = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PASTORELOC = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PADFLTUTTL = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PADFLTSTTL = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PASYNC = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAMONI = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PASTANDORT = "' + Desc + '"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAMSG = "' + Desc + '"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAMSSERVER = "SERVER_0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAMETHOD = "C"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAPROSNAME = "\\\\' + Server + "\\" + PrinterName + '"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PALOMS = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PALPRCMD = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PALPDHOST = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PALPDPORT = "0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PACONNTIME = "0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAREADTIME = "0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PATRAYS = "0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAXSHIFT = "0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAYSHIFT = "0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAXSHUNIT = "MM"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAYSHUNIT = "MM"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PACRYPTMOD = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PACRYPTMET = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PANOVSERVR = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAPOOLART = "P"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PATRACE2 = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PATRACEF = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAPROTDATA = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAPROTCMD = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAPROTRES = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PAKEEPFILE = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  CHGNAME1 = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  CHGSAPREL1 = "750"')
        f.write('\n' + '  CHGSAPSYS1 = "PR0"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PADEVGRP = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  COLORPRT = "X"')
        f.write('\n' + '  PRINTMODE = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  INPUTTRAY = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '  PANOCHOICE = ""')
        f.write('\n' + '}')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. It will be a huge timesaver.